# Java/Android: SQLite or file for indexing?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, indexing

my Android app needs to scan a directory for files and writes them all in one ArrayList.
The algorithm currently needs about 630 ms for 1273 files. Since an increase of the number of files (to 3500 and above) is very likely, I need to improve the performance.

So I was thinking about indexing. Before I waste any time on inefficent code: Is it worth the effort and time to write a indexing class for the files? If so, is it faster to use SQLite or a default *.whatever-File?

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: What else are you doing with the list of files?  So far, all you are doing is filling an ArrayList.

Comment: That's right but I am including sub-directories (recursion), which might be not the fastest way to use every time I need the data during the runtime.

Comment: My point is you need to provide more details about what you are doing before anyone can give you an answer.  How about showing some code?

Comment: My app iterates through a tree of (sub)directories and writes the path of all the included files into one big ArrayList<String>. I get your point but I just wanted to know if it would be theoretically possible to gain performance by writing all the paths once into an index and read it out at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the indexes section on http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html.

And try doing lazy load from another thread if needed.